# How to use ' instead of " in auto import in JetBrains products?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm, auto-import

When I'm programming in TypeScript and I use auto-import in WebStorm, the IDE uses the quotes " but I want it to use the single quote '.

For example, currently the IDE imports as follows:

```
import {Numbers} from "../utils/constants/numbers";
```

But I want it to be imported like this:

```
import {Numbers} from '../utils/constants/numbers';
```

I've checked the IDE settings and I don't see an option to change that behavior.

I want this behavior as I am using TSLint and it flags me an observation if the quotes " are used on the import.

It is not my intention to change the configuration of TSLint.

Comment: `Preferences | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Punctuation | Use double/single quotes` should be the correct setting to change?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, that's what I was looking for, thanks!
If you add it as an answer I will mark it as solved :)